# Prevent CL_SALV_TABLE from removing leading zeros?

Tags: abap, leading-zero, alv

Please take a look on this following piece of code in which I put zeros in Test2 as value and two zeros in Test3 as value.
i used set_leading_zero but still leading zeros are removed.

```
CLASS lcl_main DEFINITION FINAL CREATE PRIVATE.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS:
      main.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_main IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD main.
    TYPES: BEGIN OF l_tys_test,
             name  TYPE string,
             value TYPE i,
           END OF l_tys_test,
           l_tyt_test TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF l_tys_test WITH EMPTY KEY.

    DATA(lt_test) = VALUE l_tyt_test(
      ( name = `Test1` value = 1 )
      ( name = `Test2` value = 02 )
      ( name = `Test3` value = 003 )
    ).

    cl_salv_table=>factory(
      IMPORTING
        r_salv_table = DATA(lo_salv_table)
      CHANGING
        t_table = lt_test
    ).


    lo_salv_table->get_columns( )->get_column( 'VALUE' )->set_leading_zero( abap_true ).

    lo_salv_table->display( ).
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  lcl_main=>main( ).
```

Comment: value is declared as integer. There are no leading zeros for an integer type. The value of the field value is stored without any leading zero, i. e. it will never be possible to display leading zeros for an integer type.

Comment: Agreed. When you store 1, 01 or 001 in a numeric variable, it's stored exactly the same way in memory. Any further usage cannot distinguish them, ALV or whatever. If you want to display any number of leading zeroes, you will have to use a text variable.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Jozsef and Sandra, there is no way you can do it with integer data type.

The only way how to implement this by means of ALV grid is to redeclare you `VALUE` field as numchar

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF
         ...
         value TYPE n LENGTH 10,
         ...
       END OF.
```

and utilize [EDIT_MASK](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_NETWEAVER_AS_ABAP_751_IP/70396d7dec4c4f19b9ca3b2e47559d12/4ebd10e31041389ee10000000a421937.html?version=7.51.12&locale=en-US) function, which is available both for `WRITE` statement and for ALV grid as well.

Put this instead of `set_leading_zero( )` call in your method

```
lo_salv_table->get_columns( )->get_column( 'VALUE' )->set_edit_mask( '___________' ).
```

`LENGTH` specification in type definition is the number of leading zeroes to put.

Answer (score 0):

You can use set_zero method to false.

`DATA(lo_column) = lo_alv->get_columns( )->get_column( 'PERNR' ). lo_column->set_long_text( 'Staff No' ). lo_column->set_zero( abap_false ).`